# How to find the sum of all sequences in a multifasta file

Tags: fasta

I have a multifasta file containing several genes from a genomic island. I want to know the total length of this island. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? How many sequences do you have? How are the position of each sequence stored in your multifasta or elsewhere?

Comment: Most tools that calculate genome assembly summary stats will report total length. I use [assembly-stats](https://github.com/sanger-pathogens/assembly-stats)

Answer (score 5):

```
grep -v ">" multi.fasta | tr -d '\n' | wc -c
```

- `grep -v ">"` find all non header lines (i.e. without ">")
- `tr -d '\n'` delete all newlines
- `wc -c` count all characters

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a function that I keep around for calculating the individual lengths of fasta sequences

```
falens(){
awk '/^>/ {if (seqlen){print seqlen}; print ;seqlen=0;next; } { seqlen += length($0)}END{print seqlen}' $1
}
```

And one I use for summing a column of numbers

```
sum(){
awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum}'
}
```

You can combine these by piping the output to do the sum for you:

```
falens myseqs.fa | grep -v “>” | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum}'
```

(Can’t test this myself currently as I’m not at my laptop, but it’s based on 2 functions that work normally)